# ASP.NET Replacement Tokens for assembly full name

Tags: asp.net, token

SharePoint has a great array of replaceable tokens to use in ASP.NET pages to reference the current assembly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231545.aspx

Does ASP.NET have any replacement tokens - I'm particularly interested in referencing the current fully-qualified assembly name.